# replacement for Popen that doesn't start new subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I have an ETL process that runs constantly and with multiple subprocesses using ProcessPoolExecutor. In that process I need to run a few bash commands, and up until now I've used os.system because I was afraid of opening a new subprocess in my subprocess, it caused my a lot of problems in the past (memory error on my machine).
Any idea of replacement for Popen or maybe reassurance that its way of opening subprocess cant hurt.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to have a persistent `subprocess` session?

Comment: I mean, `os.system` does start a subprocess...

Comment: In any case. `subprocess` is the *recommended way of doing this*.

Comment: I had no idea that os.system starts a subprocess, Thanks for the felp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you need exactly but maybe the following infos will help you:

So basically you have the variants:

`os.system("ls -l")` executes the command passed as a string in a sub-shell ( `os.system.__doc__ 'Execute the command in a subshell.'`)

`subprocess.call(["ls","-l"])` or `subprocess.call("ls -l", shell=True)` difference being when `shell=False` is set, there is no system shell started up, so the first argument must be a path to an executable file and if `shell=True` means system shell e.g. `\bin\sh` will first spin up.

`subprocess.Popen`  direct call to the process constructor, where the command is passed as a list and you can set the `stdout`, `stderr` value to `PIPE` and call `comunicate()` to get the output.

in Python 3.5 `subprocess.run` was added as a simplification for `subprocess.Popen`. The main difference between them is that `run` executes the command and waits for it to finish while with `Popen` you can continue doing stuff while the process finishes and then just make calls to `comunicate`